# Removing ViewModels in Prism when Closing Window

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container

I have a winform application with data grid rows with some icons.
When the user clicks on one of the icons, a WPF window opens.
I have created this WPF window using Prism i.e. it has shell and regions mapped to view.

The issues I am facing is:
When I tried to close the WPF window, I get the exception "Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed."
I understand that we can resolve the issue by hiding the window instead of closing it.
However, this makes my ViewModel and Services representing the older WPF window.
I have kept the static counter in the ViewModels and observed that every time, I open the WPF window, static count increases which means my old view models are not getting destroyed.

I would like how to handle this scenario correctly so that when I close the window everything related to the window should be disposed off.
I tried to do container.dispose in ShellViewModel, however, still it did not work.

Comment: you could use the new IDialogService that Prism offers https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1682

Comment: I think IDialogService is mainly used to replace MessageBox use cases. In my case, I have a pretty complex UI on the WPF with 3 regions in a shell.

Comment: You can combine the IDialogService using your own ViewModel, Regions etc and use a scoped region manager.
Otherwise you would need to create a ShellService --> There is an answer for that already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010756/instantiating-multiple-instances-of-prism-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects here. Firstly, you can use either `RegionMemberLifetimeAttribute` on your view model or implement `IRegionMemberLifetime` to make Prism create a new instance each time.

Secondly, you have to create your own `RegionBehavior` (or take it from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/7)) to make Prism dispose view models.